# Map Generation Biome - 3D Zonation Altitude/Temperature/Moisture

Tags: procedural-generation, maps

I'm working on an endless map generator and I have a question about biomes selection.

I already have all the work done to generate PerlinNoise (actually for map altitude and moisture) but every graph I found take only account of Temperature/Moisture. (Or sometime Latitude/Moisture but as i'm into an Endless map Latitude do not exist).

**Example found on Google:**

[image]
[image]

**Questions**

- Do I can assume that height of the map represent the temparature ? So high level are always cold and under snow, but sea level are always desert.
- Do I need another noise (for Temperature) and found a 3D table to select biome (I didn't found any) ??

---

### Holdridge life zones

I also found a kind of 3D Zonation with [Holdridge life zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holdridge_life_zones) but I don't see how the 3 axis works..
[image]

I don't see how to implement my 3 axis into this (**Image (1)**).

I also try (into **Image (2)**) to create a 3D version of it, but using triangular force me to handle High as Cold and Dry ?

So I think my real need is a simple 3D axis representing all cases between [0;1] (**Image (3)**) but I never saw stuff like that ??

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you need separate noise axis for temperature and height? How should we know? We don't know your game. Only you can tell what makes sense in the context of the mechanics and aesthetics of your game.

Comment: @Philipp, I don't really "need" to, but my game actually run with 2 noises: Altitude and Moisture. So I tried to used both of them with classic 2D Zonation (Mixing Temperature and Moisture, so I have to interpret Temparature using Altitude). The second choice is just to create a new Temperature noise and use  3 to select Biomes, but I never saw a version like on my Image (3) :/

Comment: The question in its current form as some issues: you officially ask 2 off-topic (opinion based) question, and you ask something unclear in the rest of the question. Did you try to implement the 3 axis approach? It's not because it's never been done before that you can't do it yourself. Could you reword the question to ask something clear, that can be answer by something other than yes and no?